# How can I create a virtual die (for playing dice) using html and css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a virtual die (for playing dice) using CSS/HTML and JavaScript...  My JavaScript part is working, but I can't seem to get the HTML/CSS to display it the way I want (without creating a borderless table and putting each dot in a cell).  I made the following JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ShoeMaker/KwBaN/5/ and when you get a 4, 5, or 6 you can see my problem..

I want to get an analog die with a set of square brackets [ ] with the correct number of dots inside.
 1. should have one dot in the middle-middle
 2. should have one dot in the top-left and one in the bottom-right
 3. should have one dot in the top-left, one in the middle-middle, and one in the bottom-right
 4. should have one in the top-left, top-right, bottom-left, and bottom-right
 5. should have one in the top-left, top-right, middle-middle, bottom-left, and bottom-right
 6. should have three across the top and three across the bottom (or three down the left side and three down the right side).

I've thought about creating a border-less table, but I would like to try and do it with block/inline and super/sub first.
I do NOT want to display images (not allowed).
They only need to display the end result, not flicker and pretend to be rolling (although that may be cool in the future).
I don't care to make them "digital" using ASCII characters or the like. (Too traditional, like analog dice).

Any ideas my my fiddle isn't working as I intend?

Couple of minor additional notes...

- I may want to use this with "non-standard" dice ( those with 7, 9, 12, 20, ??? sides ) in the future, needs to be easily adaptable (Using ":" doesn't work).
- Would like it to be relatively small (Shouldn't take up 1/8 of the screen per die  (Yahtzee would take more than half the screen!))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things.

Span elements are already inline elements so you don't need to specify such within your css.

Note, that your "row" elements are now wrapped within a parent container with a display style of "inline-block". The inner elements were changed to be `block` elements as you want them to be "stacked" on top of each other to achieve your desired effect.

```
<span class="bracket">[</span>
<div id="die">
    <div id="TopRow">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="MidRow">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="BotRow">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<span class="bracket">]</span>

#die {
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 5px;             
}

span.bracket {
    font-size: 95px;       
}

#TopRow, #MidRow, #BotRow {
    font-weight: bold;           
}
```

​
Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KwBaN/11/

**EDIT**:
As per your comment here is another update to make the "die" a little smaller:

```
div {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0; 
}

#die {
    display: inline-block;              
}

span.bracket {
    font-size: 40px;       
}

#TopRow, #MidRow, #BotRow {
    font-weight: bold;  
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 8px;    
}
```

another updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KwBaN/34/
​

Comment: This is the closest, only I was hoping to make them smaller (the reason I was trying to use super and sub and then just have them overlap with transparent background).

Comment: The fiddle is unavailable (04/26/16).

Answer (score 2):

I did some html and css and the result is here -

http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/KwBaN/21/

**Edit:**
Updated fiddle with inline css.
http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/KwBaN/36/

Comment: Yes, This is about it...  I just wish it was inline css (call me old school, makes it easier to see for me) I'll play with it and move it inline and see if it still works... :D

Comment: @ShoeMaker - added fiddle with inline css.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<span>[</span>
<div style="display:inline-block;">
    <div id='top'></div>
    <div id='mid'></div>
    <div id='bot'></div>
</div>
<span>]</span>
```

Just add font sizes to stuff and make the id's right and it should work. It displays the dots on three rows right above each other.  Maybe mess with `line-height` to make it pretty.

Comment: I was hoping to make them smaller (the reason I was trying to use super and sub and then just have them overlap with transparent background).

Comment: Just give the top mid and bot divs a `height` css property.

Answer (score 0):

A concept like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/NuRKL/12/